# mysql index issues

Tags: mysql

My table has 1,000,000 rows and 4 columns:

```
id  cont    stat   message

1   rgrf       0   ttgthyhtg
2   frrgt      0   tthyrt
3   4r44       1   rrttttg
...
```

I am performing a select query which is very slow even though I have done indexing

```
  SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE stat='0' order by id LIMIT 1
```

This query is making my `mysql` very slow, I checked with mysql explain and found this

```
  explain SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE stat='0' order by id LIMIT 1
```

and I was shocked by the output but I don't know how to optimize it.

```
id  select_type  table   type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref      rows  Extra
 1  SIMPLE       tablea  ref   stat           stat       4  const  216404  Using where
```

There are 216,404 rows for optimizing that I have to reduce to 1 or 2 but how?

Comment: Where's the table definition?

Comment: Do you really need that `ORDER BY id`? If so, what is the id in this case? You do it to get the earliest created row?

Comment: @SergeyEremin there are several rows i am trying to extract the information of latest row whose status is 0 after extracting it will be updated  to 1

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for the row with the smallest ID number for which stat = 0?   Or the largest?  `order id limit 1` finds the smallest. I think Sergey and I are assuming that your ID is an autoincrement number? Is that correct?  If we are to help you any further you need to show us the DDL to create your table.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablea` should give you that informatio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL can only use one index per table in a query, this is index `stat` in your case. So, the `ORDER BY` is performed without use of index, which is very slow on 1M rows.
Try the following:

- Implicitly use the correct index:
  `SELECT * FROM tablea USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE stat='0' order by id LIMIT 1`
- Create a composite index, just as Ollie Jones said above.

Comment: @quassnoi  please give your advice how to do as explain shows more than 2 lac rows and its making my server dead slow

Comment: @raviloves Could you please attach your CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN when using the composite index?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try creating a compound index on (stat, id). This may allow your search / order operation to be optimized.  There's a downside, of course: you'll incur extra overhead with insertions and updates.

```
CREATE INDEX ON tablea (stat,id) USING BTREE
```

Give it a try.

Comment: i tried your advice and after that dmirty also but nothing happens